# Steam won't launch properly without terminal command

Tags: command-line, bash, steam

I noticed Steam wouldn't run when I installed it, shortly after installing [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) [15.10](/questions/tagged/15.10). So, I ran the command:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
```

And it worked fine. It won't run without the command. Is there a way I can make Steam run without going to the terminal or put that command in a bash script (which I know nothing about)

Comment: To possibly narrow it down, here are a few questions. Does `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam` work?  Does `DISPLAY=:0 steam` work?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the wrapper which starts steam:

Open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and enter the command

`sudo nano /usr/games/steam`

go down 5 lines (after the line which says "set -e") and enter your string from above:

`LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam`

This should be on a line by itself.

Now press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the file, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.  Steam will now run without needing that line typed.

Comment: All I see when I enter the sudo nano command is a blank GNU nano terminal with keyboard shortcuts in the bottom. There is no "set-e" nor is there 5 lines (it only lets me go down 1)

Comment: Does the file /usr/games/steam exist in your system?

Comment: If the wrapper is not in `/usr/games`, you might also look into `/usr/local/games`, or `/usr/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/sbin`.  In a standard installation of steam (`sudo apt-get install steam`) the wrapper is located in `/usr/games`

Comment: im not sure. I forgot to mention that Spotify doesnt seem to want to start up either, like steam, but i havent found a command to fix that.

Comment: I found a document in the /usr/games directory. Is that what you were talking about? (It has the command I put in it.)

Comment: Lets start from the beginning:  how did you install steam?

Comment: Good idea. I believe I ran the command sudo install steam -y or something like that, can't exactly remember.

Comment: K - how do you start the steam process, and what is the output of the command `whereis steam`

Comment: I usually just use the command in the question. When I try to use the `steam` command, it says this _Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1451690000)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast_     Not sure what to do.

Comment: when i run the command `whereis steam` my terminal says `steam: /usr/lib/steam /usr/games/steam /usr/share/man/man6/steam6.gz`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed it once I ran steam through the terminal using the command

```
steam
```

See what errors pop up. I didn't update my Graphics drivers, once that was done, Steam launched.

Answer (score 0):

I switched graphics card drivers, from the default one to an nvidia driver (I have nvidia cards) and the problem seems to have been corrected.