# Spotify won't launch on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: spotify

I am new to Ubuntu, and I managed to install Spotify on my machine. Trouble is, it won't launch. No error codes or popups whatsoever. I was hoping the salution could be similar to using the command in one of my other questions: [Steam won't launch properly without terminal command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716202/steam-wont-launch-properly-without-terminal-command)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Run Spotify in a terminal and post the output. I believe it requires you to manually install an older package version, but I don't remember which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install the library libgcrypt.so.11.
Find here [libgcrypt11 for 64-bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb) and here [libgcrypt11 for 32-bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_i386.deb)

Answer (score 0):

Installing old security libraries (libgcrypt.so.11) is not recommended. This version runs fine with Ubuntu 15-10:
http://repository-origin.spotify.com/pool/non-free/s/spotify-client/